# Questions on 4-vector velocities and invariance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Unfortunately, I missed a few lectures on four-vectors and I am pretty confused on how to go about solving the below question. I would be extremely grateful for any responses or solutions to enlighten my knowledge on four-vectors.

> In a particular frame of reference a particle with 4-velocity $v^\mu$ is observed by an observer moving with 4-velocity $u^\mu$. Derive an expression for the speed of the particle relative to the observer in terms of the invariant $v^\mu u_\mu$

Secondly

> Prove that the energy of the particle relative to the observer is $m_0u_iv^i$  (N.B. $m_0 =$ rest mass)

Comment: Have you gone to your professor to ask for some help? Maybe another student in the class?

Comment: No unfortunately I have not hopefully will have the chance to talk to a classmate today.was just looking through some old past papers in preparation for my upcoming test and this question confused me! Apologies for the question, I'm only new to this website and I am unfamiliar with the rules. Sorry